# C# how to get mouse position after INSERT key if pressed, after button click?

Tags: c#, keypress

I need to know how to get mouse position when I press a key (insert).

This is what I trying to do:

I have a form1 with one buuton, when you press that button it call another form. But before call the form2 i need to get mouse position from an external application. To do this, the user must hover the cursor over requested position and press 'INSERT'.

```
public partial class _CalibrateGeneralStep2 : Form
{
    public _CalibrateGeneralStep2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Restart();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();      

        ///// HERE I NEED TO WAIT UNTIL USER PRESS 'INSERT' KEY BEFORE CALL  _CalibrateGeneralStep3 /////   

        _CalibrateGeneralStep3 frm = new _CalibrateGeneralStep3();
        frm.Show();
    }
}
```

I try with keypress and keydown but I dont know use it well.

Thanks... sorry if my english is not good...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

[System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx): "It represents the current cursor position  in screen co-ordinates"

**Note:** Please refer to the example to see how it works

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `KeyDown` Event of the form (You can add it from the Designer to be sure it's wired properly)

Since you cannot just wait for the key press event inside your button2_Click, I've used a private field to store the fact that the button have been pressed. Now each time the user press Insert, you check if the button have been pressed and the cursor position. If both are correct, generate the new form.

I've defined the needed cursor position with the 2 constants at the top of the class, and you should also choose a better name for "hasButton2BeenClicked", depending of your business context haha.

```
public partial class _CalibrateGeneralStep2 : Form
{
    private const int NEEDED_X_POSITION = 0;
    private const int NEEDED_Y_POSITION = 0;

    private bool hasButton2BeenClicked = false;

    public _CalibrateGeneralStep2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        KeyPreview = true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Restart();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {      
        hasButton2BeenClicked = true;  
    }

    private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Insert && IsCursorAtTheCorrectPosition() && hasButton2BeenClicked)
        {
            GoToNextStep();
        }
    }

    private bool IsCursorAtTheCorrectPosition()
    {
        return Cursor.Position.X == NEEDED_X_POSITION && Cursor.Position.Y == NEEDED_Y_POSITION;
    }

    private void GoToNextStep()
    {
        this.Hide();
        new _CalibrateGeneralStep3().Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I use your code, but when i click the button nothing happen, just hide the form.

Comment: You have to use the Insert key and also set the cursor position at the correct place. Instead of flat values for the position check as I did, using an area would be a good idea. Also, forgot to enable the "KeyPreview" property to get key presses on the Form, fixed that.

Comment: @user2888904 Oh, overlooked you were hiding the current form. You will be unable to capture key input if it is hidden; I've moved that to after the Insert key with cursor at the correct position. If you really need to intercept the key press outside of you application, you will need to replace the KeyPressed with a Global Keyboard Hook (Google have a ton of info on that).

Comment: have been very helpful, but it have not worked, when I press the button and then pressed insert key nothing happens

Comment: @user2888904 Step in Debug mode and see what's going on, the behaviour is okay here. Stuff to watch for : Is your event correctly wired? Does the form have focus (you'll need a Keyboard hook if it's not the case)? Is the cursor at the correct spot? Is the KeyPreview enabled?

Comment: I have to say I'm noob in C#, but i dont understand how to do it works.

Comment: I did it in AutoIt     Case $Button1
   GUIDelete()
   While 1
      If _IsPressed("2D", $hDLL) Then
      $ButtonX = MouseGetPos(0)
      $ButtonY = MouseGetPos(1)
      IniWrite ($ConfigLocation, "General", "Accept_X", $ButtonX )
      IniWrite ($ConfigLocation, "General", "Accept_Y", $ButtonY )
      MsgBox(4096, $Version, "Button Calibrate. Press ACCEPT to Continue")
      DllClose($hDLL)
      _CalibrateGeneralStep2 ()
      EndIf
   Sleep(250)
   WEnd